# How to know that Telegram bot was stopped/blocked by user?

Tags: telegram-bot

What should happen when bot sends any message to user which blocked/stopped him? Can I catch this events with Bot API?

Answer (score 2):

You can understand if bot was blocked/stopped only if you send a message to a user - you will get an error. It's the only way for now :(

Comment: Is it official way or your own?

Comment: I'm checking bot status in the same way